# No validator could be found for type: java.lang.Short

Tags: java, hibernate, jaxb, hibernate-validator

I have a JAXB generated class containing the following:

```
@Pattern(regexp = "[0-9]", message = "Message details here")
protected Short msgVal;
```

When I run a JUnit test to validate an instance of that class via Hibernate, I get:

`javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: No validator could be found for type: java.lang.Short`.

If I comment out the `@Pattern` constraint, the JUnitTest runs fine.

Is it possible to have `@Pattern` constraints on Short values? If so, what am I missing?

Regards,
PM.

Answer (score 6):

@Pattern is for Strings, you cannot apply it to a Short. Instead, you can use @Max and/or @Min. @Digits may be even better.

```
@Digits(integer=1, fraction=0)
protected Short msgVal;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies. I thought that was the case myself. However, the JAXB generated class' java.lang.Short field's @Pattern annotation was generated automatically from the following XSD:

  `<xs:restriction base="xs:unsignedByte">
  <xs:pattern value="[0-9]"/>
 </xs:restriction>`

The annotation was put in place by an Xjc JSR303 annotations plugin (namely krasa-jaxb-tools), and I am wondering whether the problem is in the schema file's <xs:restriction/> or in the Xjc plugin's code itself? Thanks again, PM.

Comment: Its a bug in the plugin tool. You might want to file an issue here: http://code.google.com/p/krasa-jaxb-tools/issues/list

Comment: Did you try?
<xs:minExclusive value="0"></xs:minExclusive>
<xs:maxExclusive value="9"></xs:maxExclusive>

Comment: Sorry, did you try?
'
<xs:minInclusive value="0"></xs:minInclusive>
<xs:maxInclusive value="9"></xs:maxInclusive>
'

Comment: I am not allowed to change the schema (it is external and used by other organisations). Looking at `xs:unsignedByte` online, I believe that `xs:pattern` is allowed on an `xs:restriction` with base `xs:unsignedByte`.  I will log an issue in the krasa-jaxb-tools issues list and hopefully see what they say there. It seems strange however to have to map an `xs:pattern` restriction to an annotation other than `@Pattern`. Is this normal and usually done by JSR303 annotations plugins?

Answer (score 0):

no `@Pattern` annotation just takes arguments as String. You can use `@Digits(message="message here", integer=32767, fraction = 0)`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Please see my comment on @Robertiano's answer. Cheers, PM.