# Hibernate validator. Number field

Tags: hibernate, validation, jsp

I want to validate a jsp field. There should be a positive number (1, 100, 1000, etc). But I get an error when I put there a String value:

```
No validator could be found for type: java.lang.Long.
```

Here is a code from the model:

```
@NotNull @Pattern(regexp = "[0-9]+", message = "wrong Sort number")
private Long depOrder;
```

How could I get my "wrong Order number" message instead of that ugly error.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for my eyes it looks strange to check a Long with a regexp for numbers.
May [No validator could be found for type: java.lang.Short](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13457276/no-validator-could-be-found-for-type-java-lang-short) 
will help

Comment: How should I check it?

Comment: According to [link]http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-metadata-api point 2.2
nearest could be 

    @Digits(integer=, fraction=)
or with

     -@Min 

     -@Max

Comment: Using both @Digits and @Min I get an error `Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type java.lang.Long for property depOrder; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "we"`

Comment: Thank you. I changed error message in messages.properties.